# EDIT: UITextView Label is Cut in Half (Horizontally)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, contentsize

I need help with this peculiar problem. I have a multiple choice question app and I have the choices as UITextview. Sometimes, choice D gets cut in half for whatever reason.

Screenshot:
[image: Choice D is halved!]

Not sure what's going on here. I basically have the UITextView frame adjust to its contentSize.

```
                CGRect dFrame = choiceD.frame;
                dFrame.size.height = choiceD.contentSize.height;
                choiceD.frame = dFrame;
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `UIButton` doesn't have a `contentSize` property, does it? What is the type of the object whose `contentSize` you're getting?

Comment: Does `choiceD` know its width is fixed?  If you set `dFrame.size = choiceD.contentSize`, does it make the button fit its text by making it too wide for the space available?  Also try using `NSLog` to display the sizes before and after.

Comment: @warrenm excuse me, I meant UITextView

Answer (score 0):

Caculate the size of string:

```
    NSString *choiceDString = @"Equal the present value....";
    CGSize size = [choiceDString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:CHOICE_FONT_SIZE] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CHOICE_WIDTH, 100000)];
```

Init a label to content the choice string:

```
    UILabel *choiceDLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];
    choiceDLabel.text= choiceDString;
```

Add the subview label for button:

```
    [button addSubview:choiceLabel];
```

Comment: I will definitely give this a try later tonight. ty

Answer (score 0):

Use this code..Yo have define height of label according to your text length...

```
NSString *summary;
summary = @" your text";
CGSize sizeofbuttonorlable = [summary sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:30] 
               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT)  
                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, sizeofbuttonorlable.height);
UILabel *choiceDLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
choiceDLabel.text= summary;
[button addSubview:choiceLabel];
```

Hope, this will help you...chill

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to first Calculate the size of the text entered by you in the textView like:-

```
      //Give the maximum size of label which that label can have.
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(300,500);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [Label.text sizeWithFont:Label.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

      //adjust the label the new height.
CGRect newDescFrame = Label.frame;
newLabelFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
NSLog(@"%f",newLabelFrame.size.height);
      //adjust the label the new width.
newLabelFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
NSLog(@"%f",newLabelFrame.size.width);
      //Set the label size according to the new height and width.
label.frame = newLabelFrame;
```

Write above mention code after entering the text in the textView.
Hope it helps.Thanks :)